# Como crear una extension twig en symfony que devuelva el dia de la semana?

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3, twig

De que manera se puede crear una extension en twig, que realice lo mismo que este codigo PHP:

```
public function nombredia($nombredia)
{

    $dias = array('','Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado','Domingo');

    $fecha = $dias[date('N', strtotime($nombredia))];

    return $fecha;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar esta action se debe crear una extension que debe estar ubicado en **AppBundle/Twig/NombrediaExtension.php** con el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;


//Extension que saca el nombre del dia
class NombreDiaExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

public function getFunctions()
{

    return array(
    new \Twig_SimpleFunction('nombre_dia', array($this, 'nombre_dia')),
    );

}


public function getName()
{

    return 'nombre_dia_extension';

}


public function nombre_dia($nombredia)
{

    $dias = array('','Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado','Domingo');

    $fecha = $dias[date('N', strtotime($nombredia))];

    return $fecha;

 }
}
```

Luego de este debemos colocar el siguiente codigo dentro de: **app/config/services.yml**

```
services:
#service_name:
#    class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
#    arguments: ['@another_service_name', 'plain_value', '%parameter_name%']

app.twig_extension.nombre_dia_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\NombreDiaExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Finalmente en el archivo twig que estemos utilizando hacemos una de esta funcion:

```
{% set diasemana = nombre_dia(datos.DueDate|date("Y-m-d")) %}
{{diasemana }}
```

Saludos