# Como mostrar la edad de una persona en Symfony con twig

Tags: symfony2, symfony3, symfony, twig, yml

Tengo este código PHP que funciona pero quisiera poder utilizar lo mismo pero dentro de twig en symfony.

```
<?php
    $cumpleanos = new DateTime("1982-06-03");
    $hoy = new DateTime();
    $annos = $hoy->diff($cumpleanos);
    echo $annos->y;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar este código me guie en este post:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/73288/6524

La única variante en el archivo `EdadUsuarioExtension.php`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;


//Extension muestra la edad del usuario
class EdadUsuarioExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

public function getFunctions()
{

    return array(
    new \Twig_SimpleFunction('edad_usuario', array($this, 'edad_usuario')),
    );

}


public function getName()
{

    return 'edad_usuario_extension';

}


public function edad_usuario($fecha)
{

    $cumpleanos = new \DateTime($fecha);
    $hoy = new \DateTime();
    $edad = $hoy->diff($cumpleanos);
    return $edad->y;

 }
}
```